# APScheduler started twice on Django Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, apscheduler

I am using APScheduler (backgroundScheduler) to run a background job on Django deployed to Heroku. The job is supposed to run once every minute.

I use a view endpoint to start the scheduler. /run is eventually called multiple times but should only start one scheduler.

Locally, it works like a charm. However, when deployed to Heroku, calling /run multiple times will start another background scheduler. Interestingly, two schedulers are started, not more.

I was thinking if this could be due to threading? Maybe /run is called on different threads. Any help is very much appreciated!

**views.py**

```
def run(request):
    if cgm_receiver.scheduler.running:
        logger.info('Background service was already running')
    else:
        logger.info('Background service was not running')
        logger.info("Starting background service")
        cgm_receiver.scheduler.add_job(cgm_receiver.timed_job,
                                           id='cgm_receiver',
                                           replace_existing=True,
                                           trigger='interval',
                                           minutes=1)
        cgm_receiver.scheduler.start()

    return render(request, "run.html")
```

This is the output after calling /run first time

> at=info method=GET path="/run/" host=**** request_id=2bfe4eb3-47dc-41bc-afb9-2f1f20217d9f dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5327ms status=200 bytes=3330 protocol=https
> 2022-02-06 16:48:13,995 | INFO | cgm_importer.views : Background service was not running
> 2022-02-06 16:48:13,996 | INFO | cgm_importer.views : Starting background service
> 2022-02-06 16:48:14,001 | INFO | apscheduler.scheduler : Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
> 2022-02-06 16:48:14,001 | INFO | apscheduler.scheduler : Added job "timed_job" to job store "default"
> 2022-02-06 16:48:14,001 | INFO | apscheduler.scheduler : Scheduler started

Calling it a second time

> 10.1.0.196 - - [06/Feb/2022:16:48:14 +0000] "GET /run/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3069 "-" at=info method=GET path="/run/" host=**** request_id=1ab97b28-d148-44a8-8604-4d88cc219aca fwd="****" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=3305 protocol=https
> 2022-02-06 16:48:37,991 | INFO | cgm_importer.views : Background service was already running

Calling it a third time creates a second scheduler

> [06/Feb/2022:16:48:37 +0000] "GET /run/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3044 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36"
> at=info method=GET path="/run/" host=**** request_id=dfc8afe9-9e8a-47fd-b874-8f6da4b986a9 fwd="****" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1459ms status=200 bytes=3330 protocol=https
> 2022-02-06 16:48:53,831 | INFO | cgm_importer.views : Background service was not running
> 2022-02-06 16:48:53,832 | INFO | cgm_importer.views : Starting background service
> 2022-02-06 16:48:53,836 | INFO | apscheduler.scheduler : Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
> 2022-02-06 16:48:53,837 | INFO | apscheduler.scheduler : Added job "timed_job" to job store "default"
> 2022-02-06 16:48:53,837 | INFO | apscheduler.scheduler : Scheduler started

Comment: I suspect this is [because Gunicorn is running multiple processes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration). Are you committed to using APScheduler? I never like scheduling stuff in application code when there are better solutions out there ([Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) or possibly a [worker process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model#mapping-the-unix-process-model-to-web-apps) in this case, cron in others).

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your help! I was using APScheduler because the Heroku scheduler works against my Dyno hours and this is a free project. The task is running every minute and it’s time critical, would a cron job still work? Maybe APS might work if i choose a different job store. Right now it uses the default store which is probably within the scope of the process and changing the store to use an external database would solve the problem. I guess this is what the jobstore is about. Or is APS a bad idea for my problem?